# Text to Speech in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Does anybody know where to start from in converting text to speech in Flex 4? I did not find any clear explanation in this regard. Can somebody guide me to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a [Text-to-speech engine for Flash Player](https://github.com/edobashira/Flite-hts_engine-for-Flash)